# Calling javascript function from onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, function

Here is the javascript file http://www.zaarly.com/anywhere.js

I'm calling `Zaarly.Anywhere.open({title : 'iPad', description : 'An iPad', time : '6h', price : 200, mapCenter : 'San Francisco'});` from onclick event but it's giving this error in error console:

```
Zaarly.Anywhere is  undefined
```

The script is included successfully in header, I've checked that
Any suggestions? I'm new to javascript

I'm loading the javascript dynamically i.e. including it through javascript and it's loading correctly I've checked that

Comment: It works for me - **live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vFDFz/

Answer (score 1):

> Zaarly.Anywhere.open() is  undefined

According to that error message, `Zaarly.Anywhere.open()` does not have any properties. In fact, it's `undefined`.

So, you have to look for `Zaarly.Anywhere.open().xxxxx` in your code, and remove/adjust `.xxxxx`, depending on the context.

Comment: there's nothing like that in it. I'm not accessing any property

Comment: @UzairFarooq Show your HTML: The only cause for that error message is that you're trying to call/use a method/property on `Zaarly.Anywhere.open()`, literally.

Comment: I can't answer your question without more context. You have to post the relevant code (HTML and JavaScript). You can use http://jsfiddle.net to set up a demo.