# Including javascript file dynamically and then calling function dynamically

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, include

I've included a javascript file dynamically, here is the file http://www.zaarly.com/anywhere.js
When I call the Zaarly.Anywhere.Open() function I get this error

> Zaarly.Anywhere is undefined

If I replace contents of the javascript with a simple function and then call that function it works fine, for example this function works fine:

```
function simpleFunc() {
alert("called");
}
```

What could be the problem? The javascript file has no errors, I think it's because of including the file dynamically because it works fine if I include it normally in html file.
Any suggestions

EDIT:
Here is the html that is calling the function

```
<a href="#" style="color: black;" onclick="Zaarly.Anywhere.open();">Request on Zaarly</a>
```

If a call a simple function function such as the on above it works fine

Comment: Please do not duplicate your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329498/calling-javascript-function-from-onclick-event). When information is missing, update the question, instead of creating a new one. To be able to answer your question, you **really have to show your HTML**.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you will call Zaarly.Anywhere.Open() only after the script was loaded on page.

Comment: Created a page with following content: 
<script src='http://www.zaarly.com/anywhere.js'></script>

<a href="#" style="color: black;" onclick="Zaarly.Anywhere.open();">Request on Zaarly</a>

and it worked for me, see if there are no conflicts with other js loaded in page.